# Entity Framework Core and FOR JSON AUTO

Tags: json, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Does EF Core support `FOR JSON AUTO` for SQL Server? I have views in my database and I would like to query the view (while filtering it with a WHERE clause) and return the data back to me as `FOR JSON AUTO`.

I would like to do something along these lines:

```
string json = context.UsersView.Where(x => x.Id == userId).ForJson();
UsersViewModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersViewModel>(json);
```

Or however the syntax would go. Point is, I would like to utilize SQL Server's `FOR JSON AUTO` clause. Does this exist? I *would* include the `FOR JSON AUTO` in my view definition, but that doesn't help me, as I cannot add a `WHERE` clause to the view if it's defined that way. Also, If I'm completely missing a better way to do this, please feel free. But remember, I want the POCO model to have nested objects.

I cannot find a clean way of doing this, though it would be extremely helpful because my views are pretty complex and it would be nice to just pass the FOR JSON result into an POCO model with it's nested objects, etc.

Comment: You might want to have a look at SQL Plus Dot Net. You could generate the ADO part of your service layer and there is an option to return JSON

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I was wondering if there was an EF way of doing this (an out of the box way).  I am not going to pay for extensions to be able to do this.  If all else fails, I'll just achieve my result via a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Example SQL Procedure:

```
create procedure MyProcedure
(
    @Parameter int
)
as
begin
    declare @result nvarchar(max);
    set @result = (
        select u.*
              ,(
                select ue.*
                from UserEmails ue
                where ue.UserId = u.Id
                for json path, include_null_values
              ) as Emails
        from Users u
        where u.UserType = @Parameter
        for json path, include_null_values
    )
    select @result;
end
```

Add the following extension class to a folder near your Context:
https://github.com/snickler/EFCore-FluentStoredProcedure/blob/master/EFCoreFluent/src/EFCoreFluent/EFExtensions.cs

This extension class will allow you to execute a procedure on your context, like this:

```
public async Task<MyProcedureModel> GetMyProcedureJsonModel(int userTypeId)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    await _clientContext.LoadStoredProc("MyProcedure")
                    .WithSqlParam("@Parameter", userTypeId)
                    .ExecuteStoredProcAsync((handler) =>
                    {
                        result = handler.ReadToString();
                    });
    MyProcedureModel model = null;
    if (result != null)
    {
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyProcedureModel>(result);
    }
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no clean way to do this with Entity Framework Core.  I ended up using a Stored Procedure, where I pass the filter parameter and select the data for json.

It works as intended this way, just wish EF would incorporate formatting.  It would be an easy addition, it seems.

Comment: do you have a example how do you read the SP in EF Core? with ADO ExecuteScalar?